# Combining posts with different layouts on one page in jekyll/liquid

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to create a jekyll page with all of my posts listed sequentially. The problem is that some posts use different layouts, which are then specified in the post frontmatter. I've disabled individual page output for the posts (actually a custom category), so the layouts are partials.

For example, say I have some red posts and green posts:

**_posts/01_post1.md**:

```
---
layout: redpost
---
Post 1 (red)
```

**_posts/02_post2.md**:

```
---
layout: greenpost
---
Post 2 (green)
```

I want these to get processed using the correct layout. I also would prefer to use inheritance, which I think precludes the use of `{%include%}`.

**_layouts/post.html**:

```
<article class="post">
{{ content }}
</article>
```

**_layouts/redpost.html**:

```
---
layout: post
---
<div style="color:red">
{{ content }}
</div>
```

Then in my top-level page I want to loop over all the posts, render them using the appropriate template, and concatenate the result. Obviously no `RENDER` filter exists, although perhaps I was just unable to find it's name in the documentation.

**_layouts/index.html**:

```
<html>
...
{% for post in site.posts %}
{{ post | RENDER }}
{% endfor %}
</html>
```

The desired final HTML would then look like:

```
<html>
<article class="post">
  <div style="color:red">
    <p>Post 1 (red)</p>
  </div>
</article>
<article class="post">
  <div style="color:green">
    <p>Post 2 (green)</p>
  </div>
</article>
</html>
```

Is this possible without plugins?

Comment: What do you mean by inheritance? Other than that, this seems perfectly possible with an include called 'greenpost.html'.

Comment: @JoostS Inheritance is when one layout itself has `layout: parentlayout` front matter. It lets you make a parent layout with shared headers, footers, etc, while child layouts can customize the content. See https://learn.cloudcannon.com/jekyll/introduction-to-jekyll-layouts/#layout-inheritance

Comment: I tested both my answer and JoostS's in a test project. Code: https://github.com/sbliven/jekyll-template-inheritance/blob/master/README.md Demo: https://sbliven.github.io/jekyll-template-inheritance/

Comment: @Quantum7 Did you see the source of the _Post 1 (red)_ single post page at https://sbliven.github.io/jekyll-template-inheritance/jekyll/update/2018/01/16/post1.html ? It's an invalid HTML because your __layouts/post.html_ layout does not include a HTML DOCTYPE, html tag, head and body, etc.

Comment: @AnAurelian good point. I was only worrying about getting the homepage (https://sbliven.github.io/jekyll-template-inheritance/) to render correctly. I don't know if there's a way to render a post using a different layout in different contexts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was trivial, which is why it isn't mentioned in the documentation. A document object gets rendered with the correct template just by being printed directly:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {{ post }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, because the layout of the post (_post.html_) usually inherits from the _default.html_ layout that usually contains the HTML head, header, and footer (so that it generates a valid HTML page for the single post), and the layout of the _index.html_ page also inherits from the _default.html_ layout, using `{{ post }}` will generate an invalid HTML file with many HTML heads, headers, footers - one from the _index.html_ <= _default.html_ layout, and one from each _post_html_ <= _default.html_ layout. Just use _View page source_ in your browser to check, or use a HTML5 Validator.

Comment: True. This works better with collections with `output: false`.

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with the following? Seems like a solution to me.

**_layouts/index.html:**

```
<html>
...
{% for post in site.posts %}
    {% include post.html %}
{% endfor %}
</html>
```

**_includes/post.html:**

```
<article class="post">
  {% if post.layout == 'greenpost' %}
    {% include greenpost.html %}
  {% endif %}
</article>
```

**_includes/greenpost.html:**

```
<div style="color:green">
  {{ post.content }}
</div>
```

Comment: This approach with includes does work, but it requires that `_includes/post.html` includes a line for each possible layout.

Comment: This works, but requires an extra include file for each layout (because I want to generate both the individual page for each post, and the index page with all posts), and a post "switch" include file that includes the correct include file based on the post layout. Hoping a more elegant and straightforward solution will emerge.